# How to prevent Syn-flood on a specific port with iptables?

Tags: linux, bash, iptables, kali-linux, tcp

I was Trying Recently to prevent Syn-Flood on a server on port 2421, only one TCP Connection is permitted per second, and the Existing Connections should not be stopped, so I have used the following script but it doesn't seems to do the Trick. Is there something wrong with my script?

```
#!/bin/bash
iptables -F INPUT
iptables -F FORWARD
iptables -F OUTPUT
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2421 --syn -m limit --limit 1/second --limit-burst 3 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does work. The problem is somewhere else.

You can check whether your rule is hit at all with

```
iptables -nvL INPUT
```

Maybe you accidentally use IPv6 (if the used address is `localhost`; use 127.0.0.1 instead).

Or in addition to `iptables` its successor `nftables` is in use. Check with

```
nft list ruleset
```

Comment: It looks like it would work, but with a burst of 3, wouldn't that let up to 3 connections in one second (and then 0 for the next 2). So it's correct only on average. That may not quite be what OP meant?

Comment: @AlexisWilke I didn't do any measurements and didn't look at the source code either but my understanding from the documentation is that the initial `--limit-burst` slightly increases the `--limit` average value i.e. does not block for additional time periods; that's just not how a token bucket filter works.